# What's the type of this object? And where is it documented?

Tags: javascript, xul, xpcom

I'm not finding what's the type of this "xpcomInterface", and there's no documentation of any class with this name. Any idea?

This snippet is from Mozilla's website:

```
var next = elements.item(i+1);
var xpcomInterface = scroll.boxObject.QueryInterface(
Components.interfaces.nsIScrollBoxObject);
xpcomInterface.ensureElementIsVisible(elements);
```

**--update**

I found [boxObject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Property/boxObject) that leads to [nslBoxObject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsIBoxObject), but it have no reference to any `QueryInterface` as used above. There's also references to xulplanet.com which is no more there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `xpcomInterface` is just the name of the variable.

You should read about [XPCOM and XPCOM interfaces](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial/XPCOM_Interfaces). `QueryInterface()` is a method that all XPCOM objects must implement and gives you the possibility to "cast" an object to a certain interface:

> (...) The function `QueryInterface()` is a function provided by all components which can be used to get a specific interface of that component. This function takes one parameter, the interface that you want to get. (...)

In this example, there is some object `scroll.boxObject` (**update:** which is a `nsIBoxObject` as you found out. Note that this again is just an interface (starts with `nsI`)) that seems to implement the `nsIScrollBoxObject` interface. By using `QueryInterface`, you can access those interface's methods like `ensureElementIsVisible`.

Comment: strange, if javascript does not specify the type, why this QueryInterface exists? looks like a unneeded casting for me..

Comment: Because those XPCOM components are not necessarily JavaScript objects: *XPCOM is a cross platform component object model, similar to Microsoft COM. It has multiple language bindings, letting the XPCOM components be used and implemented in JavaScript, Java, and Python in addition to C++.* https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM As far as I understood it, it is more like a bridge between several languages.

Comment: It's not "casting" in the traditional sense - it's more that it's getting a "component" of that object (see the docs Felix mentioned).  In your case think of it as doing something like the following "for scroll.boxObject, get the interface it implements that's called 'nsIScrollBoxObject'.

Comment: `QueryInterface` is one of the three methods defined on `nsISupports`. (The other two, `AddRef` and `Release`, aren't directly available from JavaScript; XPConnect manages that for you.)